# Geolocation is not Working in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, geolocation

I am making a Weather app using openweathermap. It works fine on Desktops but on mobile Devices Geolocation is somehow not working it dose not execute 
**success or error function**.

I have tried this on many devies using https://app.crossbrowsertesting.com
but every single mobile throws an error after timeout (worked fine with desktop):

```
 $('document').ready( function(){

  $('.container-fulid').hide();
 if(!navigator.geolocation)
    {
     // throw error that browser does not support geolocations 
        $('.loader').hide();
        $('body').html('<h2>GeoLocations are not Supported by your browser Please try again with another Browser</h2>');
        // .container-fulid is still hidden
    }
function sucess(position){
    var longi =position.coords.longitude;
    var lati = position.coords.latitude;
    console.log(longi + " "+ lati);
    $.ajax({
        url :  "https://crossorigin.me/http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lati + "&lon=" + longi + "&units=metric&APPID=dd29378e1f324bc034657edf0927cdf5",
        success : function (data){
             console.log(data);

            $("#city").text( data.name + "," + data.sys.country);
            $("#condition").attr("src" ,"http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + data.weather[0].icon +".png");
            $("#discription").text(data.weather[0].description);
            $("#temp").text(Math.floor(data.main.temp) +" " +'\xB0' );
            $("#max").text(data.main.temp_max);
            $("#min").text(data.main.temp_min);
            $("#right p:nth-child(1)").text("Humidity - " + data.main.humidity + " %");
            $("#right p:nth-child(2)").text("Pressue - " + data.main.pressure + " Pa");
             $("#right p:nth-child(3)").text("Wind - " + data.wind.speed + " Meter/Sec");
            //set background image
            var d = new Date();
            imagePicker(data.main.temp , d.getHours() );
        },
        error : function (xhr,status,error){
         $('body').html('<h2>' + xhr.status+' !<br>' +xhr.statusText +'<br> </h2>' + xhr.statusCode  );
    console.log(xhr);
    }
    });
}
  function error(err)
  {
    $('body').html('<h2>' + err.message+' !<br> Please try again !!</h2>'  + '    <h3>Error Code ' +err.code+'</h3>' );
     console.log(err);
   }
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(sucess, error, {
    enableHighAccuracy: true, 
  maximumAge        : 30000, 
  timeout           : 27000
});
```

This is the error I am getting with mobile devices:

```
 Timeout expired error code : 3
```

**Here is link to my code**: 
https://codepen.io/Priyansh1161/pen/pyBwoE?editors=0010

Comment: That function is not guaranteed to ever return.  The user may choose to never make that information available, or it could time out while trying to find satellites, or it could be sitting at the prompt asking for permission to return location information.  In addition, there are some new rules going into affect about what browser features are available when a page is served `http` vs `https`.

Comment: Then what would you suggest to fix this ?

Comment: Find out the cause, then "fix" or educate, the user.  *IF* the issue is caused by the user having disabled or not answering the prompt, there is no fix -- other than to educate the user.  I've seen some sites put an arrow in screen pointing to the control the user needs to interact with next.

Comment: Its not like i haven't tried but i am short on ideas to find what could be causing it as timeout error is shown in every mobile phone irrespective of permissions ( i have tried this with / without GPS high / normal accuracy ) so i don't know how to fix it

Comment: You are mixing http & https wish is a problem. https can't load stuff from http with ajax, and geolocation won't work on chrome v50 on insecure origin any longer, so you just better have to use https everywhere!